# How can I add a stop button for this clock?

Tags: javascript

I can't add a stop button for this clock.

Here is my code:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="startTime()">Start </button>
    <div id="txt">00:00:00</div>
</body>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/318/)

How can I add a stop button to this clock?

Comment: Which clock? I don't see any code. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: use clearTimeout for your setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to save off variable `t` so that you can later call `clearTimeout(t)`.  The problem with your current code is that `t` falls out of scope at the end of `startTime` and you won't have any way of getting it back.  You could use a global variable, return `t` from `startTime`, or put the internal bits of a timer into its own scope (for example, using a class).

**Class**

http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/320/

```
function Timer() { // constructor bits here }
Timer.prototype.startTime = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = this.checkTime(m);
    s = this.checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    this.t = setTimeout(Timer.prototype.startTime.bind(this), 500);
}
Timer.prototype.checkTime = function(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
Timer.prototype.stopTime = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.t);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = new Timer();
    $('#start').click(function() {
        timer.startTime();
    });
    $('#stop').click(function() {
        timer.stopTime();
    });
});
```

**Return**

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    return setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```

You can then use

```
var t = startTime(); // starts clock, keeps reference to value returned by `setTimeout`
```

to start the clock and

```
clearTimeout(t); // stops clock
```

to stop the clock, assuming you pass around variable `t`.

**Global**

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(startTime, 500); // notice var keyword is gone
}

function stopTime() {
  clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Comment: If I click 2 times on the start button and than I stop it, it don't stop. I must click also 2 times for stop it.

Comment: @Hein yes, that's probably a bug though it's present in the original code as well.  It's because start always starts a new timeout without checking if one already exists.  Could add a conditional to the top of `startTime` like `if (this.t) return;` and ensure that `this.t` is cleared in `stopTime`.

Comment: if you don't clear it, then `this.t` will still evaluate to a truthy value even though the time is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a boolean that hold by that the start button is clicked. I use it for toggle that your clock must tick or not.

try this:

```js
var started = false;

function startTime() {

    started = !started
    tick();
}

function tick() {
    if (started == true) {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(tick, 500);
    }
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="startTime()">Start </button>
    <div id="txt">00:00:00</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/1/

Your error might be incorrect usage of setTimeout function, i think so.

```
var t = setInterval(setTheTime,1000);
```